# How to find the Kth largest difference in int[]?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time

I have an Algorithm question.

For example, there is an `int[]` array like `[1,5,4,3,7,2]`.

I want to find the kth largest difference in this array like :

```
array[i] - array[j] = kth largest difference
```

(index i must smaller than `j` and `array[i]` must larger than `array[j]`).

The output is return the `j` in this question.

My current idea:

- I can build a `int[][]` to store all the difference in the array.
- Then sorting them and find the kth larget difference.

But time complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: You probably want to add the expected result for the given example.

Comment: do I understand right that `kth_max - min = kth largest difference`?

Comment: There are some possible performence improvements you could do, like removing double values in the arrays, sort arrays and only perform action on a set of values where you expect the result, and so on.

Comment: What should be the result if there are not enough distinct elements differences in the array (e.g. if all elements of the array are equal, all possible differences are equal to `0`)?

Comment: Are pairs with `i>j` but `a[i]<a[j]` considered at all?

Comment: @dehasi No. ex: for `[8 ,4 ,1 ]` 2nd largest difference is `8 - 4 = 4` not `4 - 1 = 3`

Comment: To find the kth largest between two elements, you need to iteratate n^2 always. Don't think there's a room to improvement

Comment: An O(n*log(n)*log(n)) solution to find the kth smallest difference is presented here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-th-smallest-absolute-difference-two-elements-array/. Should be straightforward to adapt to the kth largest.

Answer (score 1):

## Example in Python

```
results = []

a = [1,5,4,3,7,2]
a_new = [(1,0), (5,1), (4,2), (3,3), (7,4), (2,5)] #(5,1) -> 5:value and 1:index
sort a_new by value # e.g. mergesort O(nlogn)
start_index = 0
end_index = len(a_new) - 1
i = -1
j = -1
diff = 0

while true: # sequential search
    if(a_new[start_index][1] < a_new[end_index][1]): #compare i and j
        tmp_diff = a_new[end_index][0] - a_new[start_index][0]
        i = start_index
        j = end_index
        diff = tmp_diff
        results.append((I,j,diff)) #add a tuple in results_list
        end_index -= 1
    else: # a_new[start_index][1] > a_new[end_index][1]
        start_index += 1
      
    if start_index == end_index: break

sort results by diff and return results[k-1]
```

I hope this help. I can't check typing error.

My Idea is: max difference is -> max_possible_element_value - min_element_value

Comment: That's looking for the maximum difference, which is not what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

You could run 2 separate methods that finds the max and min of the corresponding arrays then find the difference.

OR

You can use your method of creating a new array that finds the difference of every single value THEN find the max of that array and output that.

Then use Array sort() method to reorder an array and print out the values of max differences when called by index+1

Comment: This only works for K=1 though. What about K=2 2nd largest?

Comment: edited to work now: added Array sort() method that would make it work by organizing the array in order from greatest to least then the user would be able to call the Kth largest difference using the (index+1) value.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode-wise, it could go this way :

You can sort the current array descending, then start your calculation like so :

```
diffList = {}

calculate(array,k) :

    if (k<=0) OR (array.length < 2) OR (k > 2^(array.length-1))
        return nothing // whatever behavior you want (exception or null Integer whatever suits you)
    else
        return kthLargest(k, 0 , array.length-1, array)
    end if

kthLargest(count, upperBound, lowerBound, array) :
    if count = 0
        if upperBound != lowerBound
            return max(array[upperBound]-array[lowerBound], max(sortDesc(diffList)))
        else
            return max(sort(diffList))
        end if
    else if upperBound = lowerBound
        sortDesc(diffList)
        return diffList[count]
    else
        topDiff = array[upperBound]-array[upperBound+1]
        botDiff = array[lowerBound-1]-array[lowerbound]
        if(topDiff > botDiff)
            add botDiff to diffList
            return kthLargest(count-1,upperBound,lowerBound-1,array)
        else
            add topDiff to diffList
            return kthLargest(count-1,upperBound+1,lowerBound,array)
        end if
    end if
```

Call calculate(array,k) and you're set.

This basically keeps track of a 'discarded pile' of differences while iterating and reducing bounds to always have your final largest difference be the current bounds' difference or a potential better value in that discarded pile.

Both sorts (omitted for brevity) should make this O(n log n).

You can substitute arrays for the most convenient collections, and unwrap this into an iterative solution also.

Corrections appreciated!

Comment: So this doesn't return j as you asked, but you can replace the array elements with tuples keeping the original index.

Answer (score 1):

## Sample:

```
results = []

a_new = [(1,0), (2,5), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1), (7,4)]

start_index = 0
end_index = len(a_new) - 1

i = -1
j = -1
diff = 0

while True:
    if(a_new[start_index][1] < a_new[end_index][1]):
        i = a_new[start_index][1]
        j = a_new[end_index][1]
        diff = a_new[end_index][0] - a_new[start_index][0]
        results.append((i, j, diff))
        end_index -= 1
    else:
        start_index -= -1

    if start_index == end_index: break

print(results)
```

## Result:

```
[(0, 4, 6), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 2), (0, 5, 1)]
```

you can sort the result array then get kth diff.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in complexity `O( N * logN + N * logValMax )`. First lets sort the array. After that we can build a function `countSmallerDiffs( x )` which counts how many differences smaller or equal to x are in the array, this function has complexity O( N ) using two pointers. After that we can binary search the result in range `minVal-maxVal`. We need to find `p` such that satisfies `countSmallerDiffs( p ) <= k < countSmallerDiffs( p + 1 )`. The answer will be `p`.

Hope this helps you out! Good luck!